# ASP Net Web API is blocking requests due to CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm trying to send some requests from my angular app to my **ASP.NET Web API**

Server but the requests are blocked due to the **CORS Policy**.

**Error Message:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/api/admins/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:  Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

I have already tried to allow any hosts, headers and methods but the problem is still remaining.

**Here is my CORS Policy:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(myAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
    services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

My Angular app runs on localhost:4200 and my Server on localhost:5000.

I'm happy about any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done the required configurations for CORS policy and added new policy `myAllowSpecificOrigins` in your application, but you also need to enable it to be used

It can be enabled in Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors(myAllowSpecificOrigins); //use the policy added in ConfigureServices
    app.UseMvc();
}
```